# PHP GD imagettftext character encoding, symbol missing

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, gd

I have a string that's coming to me formatted like

```
Ciel Spa at SLSâ„¢ is a celestial dreamscape
```

I have a formatting script that changes it to

```
Ciel Spa at SLS™ is a celestial dreamscape
```

The script changes the encoding

```
return iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $str)
```

The above iconv() would normally return the trademark symbol as the normal characters TM. This won't work for me, so I have the symbol replaced with a string that I can catch later on.

```
str_replace("(TM)","™",$str);
```

This works great when I'm viewing the source in the browser, but when I push this text to imagettftext() the trademark symbol is ignored, effectively making the string

```
Ciel Spa at SLS is a celestial dreamscape
```

but of course rendered as an image.

I know that the trademark symbol is supported in the font I'm using, but I'm not sure why it's disappearing.  mb_detect_encoding() returns null, whereas for most of my strings it returns UTF-8.

I'm ready for a gritty, dirty workaround as nothing so far has worked. I tried using combinations of html_entity_decode() and str_replace() to no avail. An earlier version of the same formatting script combined a long array of UTF junk character replacements, without changing the encoding of the string, then fed it to imagettftext() and it appeared fine. I can't seem to get that back...any ideas??

Comment: Can I have the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

There is simply no trademark symbol included in the iso-8859-1 character encoding. The reason you are coming up with nothing displayed there is because you are replacing part of a valid iso-8859-1 string with a symbol that is outside the range for this character set.

You might try your utf-8 to iso-8859-1 encoding change using

```
function decode_characters($info) 
{ 
    $info = mb_convert_encoding($info, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8"); 
    $info = preg_replace('~^(&([a-zA-Z0-9]);)~',htmlentities('${1}'),$info); 
    return($info); 
}
```

This code comes from some quick research on the php man pages.